# ESXi 6.7 upgrade

Tags: vmware-esxi

This morning the host had an error loading state.tgz "insufficient resources", I decided to restart using the install usb and selected to upgrade 6.7(current) to the same 6.7, I figured this would fix the corrupt file.

But its been upgrading for over 4 hours, progress bar gets to 100% and starts again from 0.I don't know if is because its upgrading each file or if is looping over and over.

I don't want to interrupt because I'm afraid it would create more problems.

Does anybody have any experience with this situation?

the host has 2 VM's one is a DC and the second a File server, the file server is the biggest with about 600GB of files.